# Can the contents of 'around' advice be executed from a separate function?

Tags: java, aspectj

I need to execute some common code for several 'around' advices.  So, I have moved the common code to a function.  But the problem I have is that, proceed() does not work inside this common function.  Please see code below.

```
aspect MyAspect {
    pointcut myPointCut() : execution(* com.test.MyTestInterface.*(..));

    Object around() : myPointCut() {
        Object retVal = null;
        try {
            ProceedingJoinPoint pjp = (ProceedingJoinPoint) thisJoinPoint;
            myfunction(pjp);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public void myfunction(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        System.out.println("Inside myfunction()" + pjp.getSignature());
        pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

Casting thisJoinPoint to ProceedingJoinPoint doesn't work.  "Inside myfunction()" is printed, but the next statement does not execute the method that was intercepted by the pointcut.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get it to work with the traditional syntax but I think I might have a solution with the [@AspectJ Syntax](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html):

```
  @Aspect
     public class MyAspect {

    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && !within(MyAspect)")
       public Object aroundTest(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint){
        Object retVal = null;
           try {
                myfunction(thisJoinPoint);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return retVal;
       }

       public void myfunction(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
           System.out.println("Inside myfunction(): " + pjp.getSignature());
           pjp.proceed();
       }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, @Fred.  This is exactly what I did.  I figured it out yesterday and I had to note to comeback to this forum and leave an update.  You beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `proceed` invocation in the method of an anonymous class that you define inside of the around advice method. As shown in Figure 1 from [this paper](http://ssel.vub.ac.be/files/defraine-odal06.pdf):

```
interface Proceedable {
  public void doProceed();
}

public aspect MyAspect {
  public void auxMethod(Proceedable p) {
    // Can invoke p.doProceed()
  }
  void around(): somePointcut() {
    auxMethod(new Proceedable() {
      public void doProceed() { proceed(); }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Bruno.  I did not try the method you've suggested.  I got it to work using annotations as mentioned in the previous post.  I find that approach simpler.  Appreciate your response though.